# Find recursive formula - Question from exam, check my answer

Tags: proof-verification, recurrence-relations, recursion

We want to demolish and move a bridge from one location to another.

The bridge is made out of $m$ road segments all connected $[0,1]$, $[1,2]$, $[2,3]$...$[m-1,m]$

We have a given function $f$ which describes the cost of moving $j$ connected road segments, for example, say we want to move the segment $[1,3]$ then the cost would be $f(2)$ since it's $2$ road segments. if we want to move $[3,4]$ it will cost $f(1)$.

We also know that splitting a bridge costs $k$. Example, if at first we had the segment $[0,5]$ we can split it by hitting spot $4$ with a hammer to get the segments $[0,4]$ and $[4,5]$. Each such split costs $k$.

Let $c(n)$ be the minimal cost for demolishing and moving a bridge of $n$ segments.

Find a recursive formula that describes $c(n)$.

What I did:

Here is my logic, hope it is sound.

if $n=1$ then we don't have a choice, we cant split it or play around with it, we just need to move it to the new location, it will cost $f(1)$. So $c(1)=f(1)$.

Now suppose $n$ is some unknown number larger than one. Now we have a few options:

1) We could move it as one piece, it will cost $f(n)$.

2) We could break it at point $n-1$, that way we will have the segment $[n-1,n]$ and $[0,n-1]$. The cost of breaking at one point is $k$, the cost of moving $[n-1,n]$ is $f(1)$ and the cost of moving $[0,n-1]$ is $c(n-1)$, that is the lowest price. so overall, if we break at $n-1$, the cost is $c(n)=k+f(1)+c(n-1)$.

3) We could break the bridge at point $n-2$ to get the segments $[n-2,n]$ and $[0,n-2]$. As before, the cost would be $c(n)=k+f(2)+c(n-2)$

And so on, generally, if we break at point $n-i$ the cost would be $c(n)=k+f(i)+c(n-i)$.

Since we are looking at the best case, where the cost is minimal, I reached the conclusion that the minimal price would be represented by the formula $c(n)=\min_{1\leq i < n}(k+f(i)+c(n-i)),f(n)$

It's either the minimal value of $k+f(i)+c(n-i)$, or $f(n)$. whichever is lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recurrence is correct. You can reduce the number of terms to be examined, however, by observing that if you cut the bridge at all, there is always a cut at most $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ from one end, so that any of the following recurrences can also be used:

$$\begin{align*}
c(n)&=\min\left\{f(n),\min_{1\le \ell\le\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\big(k+c(\ell)+c(n-\ell)\big)\right\}\\
&=\min\left\{f(n),\min_{1\le \ell\le\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\big(k+f(\ell)+c(n-\ell)\big)\right\}\\
&=\min\left\{f(n),\min_{1\le \ell\le\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\big(k+c(\ell)+f(n-\ell)\big)\right\}
\end{align*}$$